Computing SVD of matrix inverse without defining matrix
Let's say we have a $n\times n$ matrix $A$, which is so large and sparse (as in many grid-based numerical methods) that it is impossible to hold its elements in memory. Its inverse, $A^{-1}$, is a full rank matrix and we REALLY don't want to hold it in memory. To compute the solution of $A x=b$, we can use an iterative method (say, for example, the Conjugate Gradient method) to compute the solution for $x$ with a memory requirement that is about 5-6 times $n$ (depending on implementation).
Is there anything similar for computing the SVD of $A^{-1}$? Specifically, can we compute the first (or first few) eigenvalues and eigenvectors of $A^{-1}$ using an iterative method that only requires the specification of the function that produces the rows of $A$?
I am not aware of anything, but I'm not a mathematician either. It would be nice to have something like that, so if anyone has any pointers, it would be nice.
Thanks!

If you have a sparse matrix representation in memory, there are a lot of tools, like svds. Randomized algorithms may also be suitable. "matrix-free singular value decomposition" is the keyword for literature if you only have access to a matrix-vector product routine
